# SQLITE: How can I update the table using SELECT statement within an UPDATE statement?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, sql-update

I have the following payments_2015 table:

```
ref-no  |Jan    |Feb    |Mar   |Apr    |May     |Jun
1       |       |PAID   |PAID  |       |PAID    |  
2       |       |PAID   |      |       |        |PAID
3       |PAID   |       |PAID  |PAID   |PAID    |PAID
4       |PAID   |PAID   |      |PAID   |PAID    |
5       |PAID   |       |PAID  |       |        |
6       |       |       |      |       |        |PAID
```

I am checking for each ref_no how many months are NOT paid using the following query:

```
for(int i = 0; i < all_refNo_list.size(); i++) {
        qryTxt = "INSERT INTO late_payments "
                "select ref_no AS ref_no, sum(i_count) as unpaid_count from ("
                "SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN January = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS i_count, 1 AS month_no FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN February = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 2  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN March = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 3  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN April = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 4  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN May = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 5  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN June = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 6  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN July = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 7  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN August = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 8  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN September = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 9  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN October = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 10  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN November = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 11  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT ref_no, CASE WHEN December = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 12  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                ") A Where ref_no = " + all_refNo_list[i];

        query.prepare(qryTxt);
        if (!query.exec())
        {
            qDebug() << "Error" << query.lastError().text();
        }
    }
```

The result is the following `late_payments` table:

```
ref_no   |unpaid_count
1        |3 
2        |4
3        |1
4        |2
5        |4
6        |5
```

Now, if I insert 'PAID' in Jan for ref_no = 1, the result still the same. Of course it will remain the same because I am INSERTing already existing record and not UPDATing.

I am unable to update these values whenever a month is checked as 'PAID' for specific 'ref_no'. i.e.: UPDATE the table whenever there is a change.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following :

```
for(int i = 0; i < getAllRefNoList().size(); i++) { 
qryTxt = "UPDATE late_payments "
                "SET unpaid_count = ("
                "select sum(i_count) as unpaid_count from ("
                "SELECT CASE WHEN January = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS i_count, 1 AS month_no FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN February = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 2  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN March = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 3  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN April = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 4  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN May = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 5  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN June = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 6  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN July = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 7  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN August = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 8  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN September = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 9  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN October = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 10  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN November = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 11  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                " UNION SELECT CASE WHEN December = 'PAID' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , 12  FROM payments_" + getCurrentYear() +
                ") A WHERE ref_no = " + getAllRefNoList()[i] + ")";

        query.prepare(qryTxt);
        if (!query.exec())
        {
            qDebug() << "Error" << query.lastError().text();
        }
```

But no success ..

**P.S.:** I am implementing these selection statements on Qt for a c++ application. I am displaying the results of the select statements on `QTableView` using `QSqlQueryModel`.

Comment: Does your UPDATE work? What error do you get? What else have you tried?

Comment: Your select statement returns two values, but you only want to update one - try `SELECT count FROM A WHERE ref_no = 1`.

Comment: Try with `UPDATE B SET count = (SELECT count FROM A WHERE ref_no = 1) AS C`

Comment: What do you mean with "change"?

Comment: @CL. .. I meant whenever there is a change in the payment_2015 table, the late_payment should reflect that new change and update the `unpaid_count` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a single query to compute the desired table:

```
SELECT refno,
       (ifnull(Jan, '') != 'PAID') +
       (ifnull(Feb, '') != 'PAID') +
       ...
       (ifnull(Dec, '') != 'PAID) AS unpaid_count
FROM payments_2015;
```

Then you can drop that table, and instead use a view that generates these results dynamically:

```
CREATE VIEW late_payments_2015 AS
SELECT ...;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. your statement is even much easier to write and follow than mine ...

Answer (score 1):

Update statement for your select statement is:

```
UPDATE A
    SET COUNT = <your value>
WHERE ref_no = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I know the UPDATE statement syntax. It is the mixing the `SELECT` with `UPDATE` in the same query which I am struggling with..

Comment: The `<your value>` here is a `SELECT` statement but your solution didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two tables here.  One method is:

```
update b
    set count = (select count from a where ref_no = 1);
```

This will update all the rows in `b`.  You question does not suggest any way to limit it to one or a handful of rows.

Comment: You are correct I am not specifying the number of rows. Please check the question update for more explanation.

Comment: I am sorry your answer did't work as I have two level of `SELECT` statements. the `a` in your answer is another `SELECT` statement.